# Tooltip flickering when hovered on chart

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have created custom tooltip for my chart in chartjs. But the issue comes when I hover on the chart, the tooltip starts flickering. Anyone knows how can I prevent this? Thanks!

```
if (!tooltip) {
               var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
               tooltip.id = 'tooltip';
               document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
            }

            if (!model.opacity) {
               tooltip.style.display = 'none';
               return;
            }

            tooltip.innerHTML = `<div class="tooltip-body">
                                            <label>` + model.body[0].lines[0] + `</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tooltip-caret"></div>`;

            tooltip.style.display = 'inline-block';
            tooltip.style.position = 'absolute';
            tooltip.style.top = getTooltipPosition().y + 'px';
            tooltip.style.left = getTooltipPosition().x + 'px';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TRY setting style - [**`pointer-events`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to **`none`** , for the tool-tip element, like so :

```
...
tooltip.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})
```

To

```
google.charts.load('42', {'packages':['corechart']})
```

There is bug in current version.kindly use 42 version.It solved issue for me.